# access a class variable from within an object in that class in java

Tags: java

i have class A containing an object from class B and i want to access the data in class A from within class B. is there a way to access integer variable 'a' from within class B?

```
    public class A{

    int a;

    B b = new B();

    }

    public class B{

    /*want to access integer variable 'a' in class A from here*/

    }
```

Comment: Since every a in some A can be different, you first need an concrete object of type A, to get that's A.a.

Answer (score 0):

Yes all you have to do is pass class A to class B and save it as a variable

```
public class A{

    int myNumb = 5;

    B b = new B(this);

}

public class B{
    A a;
    public B (A a){
        this.a=a;
        test();
    }
    public void test(){
        System.out.println(a.myNumb);
    }
}
```

---

However I would recomend using getter

```
    public class A{

    int myNumb = 5;

    B b = new B(this);
    public int getmyNumb(){
        return myNumb;
    }

}

public class B{
    A a;
    public B (A a){
        this.a=a;
        test();
    }
    public void test(){
        System.out.println(a.getmyNumb());
    }
}
```

Comment: if i change integer variable 'a' in class B will it be changed inside passed class A? i mean is class A passed by reference or value?

Comment: did you try doing that? what did you observe?